# Working with cookies in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

For an assignment I had a few weeks ago we were asked to create two divs, one which collects and saves diary entries and one which displays the diary entries. We were asked to use the HTML form element and this should be proccessed using JS. Since it wasn't a server-side assignment were were asked to store the submitted diary entries using cookies I didn't get the assignment out and since the lecturer never posted the solution or went through a solution I was wondering if someone would be able to look at mine and show me how to do it. I was unsure how to actually set the cookie and return it. I'll also post a link to the js fiddle if that helps anyone. 
So in short, I want to be able to save the values of the input box one the save entry button is clicked, and show this value once show diary is clicked

Thanks in advance

```
HTML
    <form name ="name" onsubmit="return doSomething();">
        Please Enter Your Diary Entry: <input type="text" name=“somename” id="frm_somename"/>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save Entry" />
    </form>
    <div id = "1">
        <button id="button" onclick="y();">Show Diary</button>
    </div> 
JS
    doSomething = function() {
     // get the data from the form
     var textValue = document.getElementById("frm_somename").value;
     // the rest of the code goes here



 // return false to stop form going somewhere - NB
 return false;
}
```

Here's the link for the js fiddle also if that's any help https://jsfiddle.net/jon123/m957kc84/

Comment: there are tons of examples on how to use cookies and buttons click

Comment: just for future reference localStorage can serve the same purpose but its api is much easier than the cookie api. and indexed db could also work and is also probably easier than cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily using just vanilla javascript... JavaScript can create, read, and delete cookies with the document.cookie property. [This resource](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) should answer all of your questions.

Also you are going to need to rewrite your JS... currently you dont have an appropriate click handler function created among some other issues.

Comment: Maxwell, it's a good practice to include some relevant code incase the linked resource is changed or removed in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in Javascript in two ways:-

1. **Using Cookies**

   To simplify your work with cookies, you can use the [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) library. So, adding data to cookie can be easily achieved as follows:-

   ```
   Cookies.set('diaryEntry1', 'This is a test diary entry.');
   //In order to get the values stored in a cookie, you can do this-
   Cookies.get('diaryEntry1');
   ```

   When creating a cookie you can also pass an Array or Object Literal instead of a string in the value. If you do so, js-cookie will store the string representation of the object according to `JSON.stringify`:

   ```
   Cookies.set('diaryEntries', { entry1: 'Diary entry 1', entry2: 'Diary entry 2' });
   //When you will try to get this, it will return a string representation of the object.
   Cookies.get('diaryEntries'); // => '{"entry1":"Diary entry 1", "entry2":"Diary entry 2"}'
   ```
2. **Using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)**

   Local storage is a part of web storage, which itself is part of the HTML5 specification. In simple terms, all that `localStorage` does is store named key/value pairs locally and *unlike cookies this data persists even if you close your browser* or turn off your computer.

   ```
   window.localStorage.setItem('diaryEntry1', 'This is a test diary entry.'');

   window.localStorage.getItem('diaryEntry1');
   ```

   The support for `localStorage` is pretty good for an HTML5 specification; it is supported by all the major browsers and even IE8, so the only thing you might need to be wary of is IE7 if you’re still supporting that.

In my opinion, you should go for localStorage since my guess would be that you would like to keep the data even after the user closes the browser. Hope this helps!